# Why the modified source code of the openssl does not work

Tags: c, openssl

I tried to change the source code of the `openssl`, e.g. *dhparam.c*
I Added the printf just like below:

```
printf("This is in dhparam\n");
BIO_printf(bio_err,
                   "Generating DH parameters, %d bit long safe prime, generator %d\n", num, g)
```

After compile and install, I run the `openssl` command, the result is:

```
openssl dhparam -out dh.pem 2048

Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
...
```

There is no message I added is shown. So does any one know the reason?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the program has closed stdout, which printf is trying to write to. Maybe you should use BIO_printf(bio_err, ..) for output.

Comment: Without examining the source, it could be closing the stdout stream or closing the underlying file POSIX descriptor (typically file descriptor 1), or dupping the underlying file descriptor to /dev/null. Does printf return -1 indicating an error?

Comment: No, I used the BIO_printf, but still does not work

Comment: Where did the "safe " and the ", generator 2" in the output you posted come from? It might not be running the code you think it's running.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong code, I will re-edit it.

Comment: try modifying the second string and see if the changes show up

Comment: Already did, I remove the Generating string, but nothing changed. I run make clean to remove all the *.o file and re-compiled again to create the openssl execute file, but still cannot see any change, it's very odd.